# Error in React config folder while installing/using a Material UI component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am building my first app in React and installed Material UI for the first time.
While inserting a form component into my JSX, I get this error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useContext')" coming from a folder node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js which I imagine is the "backend" of React.

Here is the error :
[image]
[image]

Here is the code :

```js
import React from "react"
import {TextField} from '@mui/material'

function Homepage(props) {
  return (
    <section className="homepage-section white-bg">
      <div className="section-top">
        <h2><strong>Contactez-nous</strong> si vous avez la moindre <span className="special-font"> question </span></h2>
        <h3>Que vous souhaitiez proposer des <strong>actions</strong> ou tout simplement rejoindre la <strong>communauté</strong> !</h3>
      </div>
      <TextField />
    </section>
  )
}
```

I have absolutely no idea on how to fix that myself.
Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just fix it with installing this:

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

from Material UI installation page

Materialui:
[image: Materialui]

Answer (score -2):

I manage to fix this issue by uninstalling MUI and reinstalling !